# php nested check for array key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a situation where I want to check for a key 2 levels deep in a PHP array. So my code currently looks like...

```
    if(array_key_exists($needleBox, $haystack)) {
        if(array_key_exists($needle, $haystack[$needleBox])) {
            // do stuff with value attached to $needle
        }
    }
```

Where I first check for the array containing my needle (`$needleBox`), then check for the needle if `$needleBox` is found.

Is it safe to skip the check for `$needleBox` & use...

```
    if(array_key_exists($needle, $haystack[$needleBox])) {
        // do stuff with value attached to $needle
    }
```

or to check for both together in one `if` statement like...

```
    if(array_key_exists($needleBox, $haystack) && array_key_exists($needle, $haystack[$needleBox])) {
        // do stuff with value attached to $needle
    }
```

I consider the first alternative preferable for being more concise.

Comment: First alternative will throw a warning if that key doesn't exist so you will need to suppress that (using @).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why dont you use `isset`. which i much more prefer it.. `isset` is much faster than `array_key_exists`. BTW `isset` will return false if the value is null..

```
if (isset($haystack[$needleBox]) && isset($haystack[$needleBox][$needle])) {
     //code
}

OR

if ($haystack[$needleBox][$needle] ?? null)) {
     //code
}
```

EDIT agreed with @shawn advise

```
if (isset($haystack[$needleBox][$needle])) {
     //code
}
```

Comment: I like that, & will accept the answer as soon as allowed. Thank you.

Comment: You do NOT need to repeat the key check. just write `isset($haystack[$needleBox][$needle])` is OK

Comment: Agreed with @shawn. If `$haystack[$needleBox][$needle]` is set it means `$haystack[$needleBox]` is also set

Comment: This answer, & the comments, have me thinking I've been using `array_key_exists` in a lot of situations where `isset` would be more appropriate.